# C Array - Largest number and it's location

Tags: c, arrays, numbers, location

I wrote a code to 5x6 random numbers in array, how can I find largest number in it and then print it's location (x,y)?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
 int array[5][6];
 srand(time(NULL));
 int x, y;
 for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
        array[x][y] = rand() % 31 + 10;
        printf("%d \t", array[x][y]);
   }
   printf("\n");
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int max = 0; ... if (array[x][y] > max) max = array[x][y];`

Comment: And here's the [RTWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just note it when you are filling the array in the first place....?  :)

Answer (score 5):

```
int maxX = -1, maxY = -1;
int maxValue = 0
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
        if(maxValue <= array[x][y]) {
            maxValue = array[x][y];
            maxX = x;
            maxY = y;
        }
    }
}
// print maxX and maxY and maxValue
```

Comment: Does it make sense to *not* create a separate variable `maxValue`? After all, you know the value -- it's `array[maxX][maxY]`, and you can safely initialize maxX and maxY to 0.

Comment: @Jongware - in the general case the 2d array 'could' be empty, so having maxX and maxY set to 0,0 would be disingenuous. In this specific case, no you don't really need a maxValue and could simply use the indexers.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I notice this:

```
array[x][y] = rand() % 31 + 10;//So the values are between 10 and 40;
```

So:

```
 int maxX = -1, maxY = -1;
int maxValue = 0
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
        if(maxValue <= array[x][y]) {
            maxValue = array[x][y];
            maxX = x;
            maxY = y;
            if (maxValue == 40)//I add this in fact :) 
                 break;
        }
    }
}
 printf("the max value's locate %d,%d\n",maxX,maxY);
```

Comment: But then what if more than one location has a 40 in it?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson this print the first one.Here is different with answer 1,That print the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void){
    int array[5][6];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x, y;
    int max = INT_MIN, *maxp=&array[0][0];
    for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
            if(max <(array[x][y] = rand() % 31 + 10)){
                max = *(maxp = &array[x][y]);
            }
            printf("%d \t", array[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("max=%d\n", max);
    ptrdiff_t pos = maxp - &array[0][0];
    size_t column_size = sizeof(array[0])/sizeof(array[0][0]);
    x = pos / column_size;
    y = pos % column_size;
    printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int xMax, yMax, max;
xMax = yMax = 0;
max = array[0][0];

for(x=0;x<5;x++){
    for(y=0;y<6;y++){
        if(array[x][y] > max) {
                    max = array[x][y];
            xMax = x;
            yMax = y;
        }
    }
}
```

this should work for you

Comment: You forgot to max=array[x][y].